# MySQLでテーブルを全て、または正規表現で指定して削除する方法

Tags: mysql

MySQLの`DROP TABLE`は`DROP TABLE TABLE1 TABLE2`のように列挙することでまとめて削除できますが、全て削除したい、または正規表現で指定して削除するための方法を共有します。

テーブル例

```
データベース名：test_database
テーブル：
    table_2012
    table_2012_test1
    table_2012_test2
    table_2013
    table_2014
    table_2014_test1
    table_2015
```

testとついているテーブルだけを削除したいとします。

削除対象

```
データベース名：test_database
テーブル：
    table_2012_test1
    table_2012_test2
    table_2014_test1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux環境のみとなりますが、テーブル名の一覧を取得し、`egrep`で正規表現による絞り込みを行い、`xargs`で対象テーブルを渡すことで実現できました。

```
mysql -h ホスト名 -u ユーザ名 -pパスワード -D test_database -e "show tables" -s | egrep "test" | xargs -I "@@" echo mysql -h ホスト名 -u ユーザ名 -pパスワード -D test_database -e "DROP TABLE @@"
```

危険な操作なので、参考URLに倣ってechoでコンソール表示するだけにしてあります。
実際にテーブルを削除する際はコマンド内の`echo`を削除して実行してください。

全てのテーブルを削除する際は、`egrep`のパイプは不要です。

参考URL：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456751/drop-mysql-databases-matching-some-wildcard